# Как вывести данные из таблицы MSSQL SERVER; В DataGrid WPF C#;

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid

Есть база данных. В ней есть таблицы. Мне нужно вывести на экран заполненные строки из этой таблицы. Как это сделать!?
Пробовал так, не получалось:

```
 public class Student
    {
      public int Number_Students { get; set; }
      public string First_Name_Students { get; set; }
      public string Last_Name_Students { get; set; }
      public string Mid_Name_Students { get; set; }
    }
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Строка подключения);
    string cmd = "SELECT * FROM название таблицы";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd,connection);
    connection.Open();
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read())
    {
      Student st = new Student(); // создаю экземпляр класса студент;
      st.Number_Students = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
      st.Mid_Name_Students = reader[1].ToString();
      st.Last_Name_Students = reader[2].ToString();
      st.First_Name_Students = reader[3].ToString();
      students.Add(st);
    }
      reader.Close();
      StudentsGrid.ItemsSourse = students;
```

Выводятся просто пустые строки без данных [image: Вывод при запуске]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что не получилось? Ошибки?

Comment: Просто выводится окно, с пустыми строками

Comment: то есть строки есть, просто данных в них нет?

Comment: Данных в строках нет, да @tym32167

Comment: Поставьте точку останова на `StudentsGrid.ItemsSourse = students;` и посмотрите значение `students` - количество студентов и их свойства.

Comment: Количество студентов 12, как и в моей таблице, а их свойства равняются null @Bulson

Comment: @Bulson прикрепил скрин

Comment: Тогда ставьте точку останова на `while(reader.Read())` и далее шагами вперед проверяйте почему свойства получаются null. Значения строк лучше получать через `reader.GetInt(0)`   `reader.GetString(1)` и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Код C#**

```
private void DeportamentsView(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Название сервера; Initial Catalog=Название бд; Integrated Security=True");

            connection.Open();
            string cmd = "SELECT * FROM Students"; // Из какой таблицы нужен вывод 
            SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);
            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataAdapter dataAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(createCommand);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Students"); // В скобках указываем название таблицы
            dataAdp.Fill(dt);
            StudentsGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView; // Сам вывод 
            connection.Close();

        }
```

Код WPF(XAML)

```
<DataGrid   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="642" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="StudentsGrid">

    </DataGrid>
```

Проблема была в том, что у меня были сразу созданы колонки, и в них я записывал данные, но они не отображались, помогло поставить Автогенерацию колонок **AutoGenerateColumns="True"** Вывод из таблицы происходит. Но название колонок будет таким же как и в самой базе данных  MS SQL SERVER